# How to download big file with stream and JWT in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to download a zip file with a size of 300mb, I do it in Node.js with stream (so the download is byte by byte).

```
request('https://...').pipe(res);
```

The problem is I need to send a token to download this file in the header.

How to do it? Because I try to do it with this code:

```
      let a = document.createElement('a');
      a.href = `/api/download`;
      a.target = '_blank';
      a.download = 'test.zip';
      document.body.appendChild(a);
      a.click();
      document.body.removeChild(a);
      console.log('done');
```

It works when I turn off the token required. (but I need to send this token).

I also try this code:

```
axios({
  url: 'http://localhost:5000/api/download',
  method: 'GET',
  responseType: 'blob', // important
  headers: {
   Authorization: "Bearer <insert_your_JWT_here>"
  }
}).then((response) => {
  const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([response.data]));
  const link = document.createElement('a');
  link.href = url;
  link.setAttribute('download', 'file.zip');
  document.body.appendChild(link);
  link.click();
});
```

But what this does is download the file (300mb) and after it's downloaded, it begins to download to the disk (this is bad).

[image: request info]

So, how to download file as stream and with token?

Comment: piping to res or not you still need pass any token to request call, presuming the token is to access `https://...`

Comment: also plopping 300mb in browser memory/dom wont work

Answer (score 0):

So, in your code i don't see place where you keep your token.

You can use [bearer](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/authentication/bearer-authentication/)

Try simple example:

```
axios({
  url: 'http://localhost:5000/api/download',
  method: 'GET',
  responseType: 'blob', // important
  headers: {
    Authorization: "Bearer <insert_your_JWT_here>"
  }
}).then((response) => {
 //your code
});
```

Comment: as I told in my question, this is a problem cause "But what this does is download the file (300mb) and after it's downloaded, it begins to download to the disk (this is bad)."

Comment: @JonSud try this example, without any library, only pure JS
https://gist.github.com/igrigorik/5736866